# Disable ASL/NSLog at runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos

It's easy to "disable" `NSLog` at compile time by replacing it with a macro, etc.

Can `NSLog` (or ASL in general) be disabled *at runtime*?

My goal is to silence some logs that I do not have control over.

Comment: You can http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300673/is-it-true-that-one-should-not-use-nslog-on-production-code/17206296#17206296

Comment: @Lefteris that is done at build time, not at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [Lumberjack Framework](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack). There you can set the logging level as required. To hide certain log statements when you release the app, just change the logging level from say DEBUG to INFO using #ifdef RELEASE and #ifdef DEBUG macros.

Update:

In case the log statements are coming from a different framework that you are linking, you can use something like [Method Swizzling](http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/) to swap the implementation of NSlog with your custom method.

Comment: Will that silence a `NSLog` call? I cannot just replace the log calls with `DDLog` or anything else, they are in a pre-compiled framework.

Comment: Please see updated answer.. lmk in case you need more details about method swizzling.

Comment: How do you swizzle `NSLog`? It's a foundation foundation rather than a objective c method.

Comment: I don't see any reason why we won't be able swizzle foundation methods (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553017/customizing-nslog-function-on-iphone), but it is not recommended as your app might be rejected from the store. Since the OP wanted to disable logging that might be happening from another framework, this was the only way that came to mind.