# How to suppress console output of AVPlayer.play() in iOS 10 beta?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer, swift3, ios10

I use `AVFoundation.AVPlayer.play()` to play audio from a remote source.  In the preview of iOS 10 and XCode 8.0 beta (8S128d) released at WWDC 2016, this method sends a lot of information each second to the XCode console:

```
2016-07-04 14:27:58.982694 MyApp[8622:984983] [AQ] 3269: aq@0x7fa27e00d000: ptr 0x7fa27b877f23, size 0x344, ID 6244
2016-07-04 14:27:58.983794 MyApp[8622:984983] [AQ] 3269: aq@0x7fa27e00d000: ptr 0x7fa27c814920, size 0x1a2, ID 6245
2016-07-04 14:27:58.984329 MyApp[8622:986313] [AQ] 3252: aq@0x7fa27e00d000: ptr 0x7fa27b60f1f0, size 0x1a2, user => ID 6251
2016-07-04 14:27:58.985039 MyApp[8622:984983] [AQ] 3269: aq@0x7fa27e00d000: ptr 0x7fa27f014e91, size 0x4e6, ID 6246
2016-07-04 14:27:58.985958 MyApp[8622:986313] [AQ] 3252: aq@0x7fa27e00d000: ptr 0x7fa27d81627c, size 0x4e6, user => ID 6252
2016-07-04 14:27:58.986889 MyApp[8622:986313] [AQ] 3252: aq@0x7fa27e00d000: ptr 0x7fa27b75a950, size 0x1a2, user => ID 6253
2016-07-04 14:27:58.987595 MyApp[8622:986313] [AQ] 3252: aq@0x7fa27e00d000: ptr 0x7fa27d05d78c, size 0x344, user => ID 6254
```

This doesn't happen with `AVPlayer.play()` in iOS 9 and XCode 7.

What is this information and how can I suppress it?

Comment: OS betas tend to have much more logging enabled than final releases.

Comment: Curiously, I don't see this output in the console when the app is deployed to a device.  I see my own `print()` statements though.

Comment: Consider my answer on disabling logging here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35881034/2415822

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @rickster mentions, it's likely just due to being a beta release.